# TMCache - using Blocks to Monitor Cache Events

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks

From the documentation:

```
/**
 A block to be executed just after an object is added to the cache. This block will be excuted within
 a barrier, i.e. all reads and writes are suspended for the duration of the block.
 */
@property (copy) TMMemoryCacheObjectBlock didAddObjectBlock;
```

I'm trying to make use of this to print a message when objects are added to the cache. My attempt so far:

```
[[_timedCache memoryCache] setDidAddObjectBlock:^{
    NSLog(@"added something to cache");
}];
```

This gives a "parameter type mismatch" compiler error however. I'm fairly new to Objective-C and am probably doing something naive here. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`TMemoryCahceObjectBlock`](https://github.com/tumblr/TMCache/blob/master/TMCache/TMMemoryCache.h#L21) has the following signature: `(TMMemoryCache *cache, NSString *key, id object)`, which your block doesn't have. Change the signature of your block and you are golden.